# Sent Text input as byte[]

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, arduino

I want to transmitt an IP-Address from a Text-Input on a webpage over WebSockets to my Arduino, where i want it to be handled as such and not as a char*.

What i have written so far is:

HTML:

```
<tr id="network1" style="display: none;">
            <th>Client IP</th>
            <th>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="ipInput" id="inputClientIP1" oninput="checkClientIP()">
                    .
                    <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="ipInput" id="inputClientIP2" oninput="checkClientIP()">
                    .
                    <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="ipInput" id="inputClientIP3" oninput="checkClientIP()">
                    .
                    <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="ipInput" id="inputClientIP4" oninput="checkClientIP()">
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
```

The JS to send the data via Websocket:

```
 function sendData(){
 ws.send(document.getElementById("inputClientIP1").value + "," + document.getElementById("inputClientIP2").value + "," + document.getElementById("inputClientIP3").value + "," + document.getElementById("inputClientIP4").value
 };
```

The arduino just recieves the IP as a char *.
The Message that gets send is `"192, 168, 178, 100"`

Is there a good way to get the ip as a byte?

PS I have tried to change the inputs to `type="number"` but with no other result

Comment: `ip.fromString(ipString);` but first replace `,` with `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the `value` property is usually going to be a string

Even when you change the type to number you are still converting it to a string with `+","` so the result will always be a string
Without seeing exactly how the Arduino is handling the web socket code it is impossible to know how this is working, but if you want to send binary data in general in web socket you can make an uint8array and send it

```
ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
var buf = new ArrayBuffer (4)
var byteArr = new Uint8Array(buf)

byteArr[0] = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputClientIP1").value)

byteArr[1] = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputClientIP2").value)

byteArr[2] = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputClientIP3").value)


byteArr[3] = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputClientIP4").value)


we.send(byteArr)
```

Comment: it should be parsed in Arduino

Comment: @juraj Arduino code wasn't posted though, seems like OP only wants help with JavaScript